# error uploading ios app to itunes connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes, mapbox

i have added a mapbox map to an app that was already published but when i tried to reupload the archive from xcode i get the following errors.

[image: Uploading error]

is there anywhere in the mapbox framework i can change the minSDK to an allowable value (if that is the problem?)

I have tried changing the value in the info.plist of the framework but that did not help.

Comment: You can't use Beta tools to submit apps.

Comment: beta Tools? i did not set the 9.3 anywhere all references are in the mapbox framework @rmaddy

Comment: Ah. I didn't read that close enough. Perhaps you have downloaded the wrong copy of the Mapbox framework.

Comment: @rmaddy  - I installed mapbox as per the instructions on the getting started page using cocoapods. dont see how it would be a wrong copy.

Comment: I would appreciate an explanation/ recommendation on down votes

Comment: Downvote wasn't mine. You should contact Mapbox and point out this issue. They may have put out a bad version or their instructions might need to be updated.

Comment: @rmaddy Cheers  i have contacted them now. just thought might get a quicker answer here. Also last comment was a general comment not directed at you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapbox iOS SDK v3.1.0 was accidentally built with a beta version of Xcode and targeted the wrong iOS version — see https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/3870.

This is fixed in the v3.1.1 release.

Comment: Thanks. Yes just got this answer from Mapbox over the weekend.